# How can one filter LOCAL ADS for LOCAL CUSTOMERS

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation, iptables

I run a local blog, and I would like to offer advertisers the ability to buy ads knowing all of the impressions will be from the local community. For everyone else I want it to show typical google ads.

My questions are:

How feasible is this?

Is there any readily available code or service that can do something like this?

The cheaper the better, as I can do some basic coding myself. I've read a little bit about ipTables but haven't delved too deep into it. If anyone can offer some suggestions, would greatly appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite feasible.

Open X supports geotargeting.  http://www.openx.org/support/geotargeting

I believe you can also use other ad providers to do geotargeting.